# npm update error on wsl windows 10

Tags: node.js, linux, windows

I am trying to update npm using `npm update` and getting error:

```
/root/.nvm/v0.10.25/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf/config-defs.js:261
  , "local-address" : Object.keys(os.networkInterfaces()).map(function (nic) {
                                     ^
Error: EINVAL, invalid argument
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/v0.10.25/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf/config-defs.js:261:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/v0.10.25/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf/npmconf.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: node 0.10 is pretty ancient and years out of support. Have you tried a more recent version of node, specifically 4, 6, 8, or 9?

Comment: application only work with node 0.10 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest npm version that works on node 0.10 is v2.15.1; if you've managed to install a newer version, then you can try `npm install -g npm@2.15.1`; otherwise, you'll have to reinstall your entire `node` version.

Using `nvm`, you can do `nvm install-latest-npm` and it will install the latest npm version that works on your version of node, which is much more precise than `npm update`.